# Is it possible to create a timeseries graph of an SLO in Datadog?

Tags: graph, time-series, datadog

Is it possible to graph an SLO as a time-series graph using just native Datadog components?

If so, how?

I can only find a way to show an SLO as a number, I'd like to show how it changes over time in a graph-format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to graph the historical behavior of the SLI from an SLO.

The closest you could get would be to measure the underlying metric, so if you had `good events`/`bad events` you could display that percentage. But the calculation of how often that percentage is above or below a certain threshold would not be possible.

I recommend reaching out to support@datadoghq.com to let them know it's a feature you're interested in. They might be able to provide some updates.